# What is the value allowed for runway transverse slope?

Tags: runways

What is the range allowed for transverse slope for runways used by commercial aviation?

Comment: Which country? Which size of runway? Which pavement surface? I have flown into a lot of dirt or gravel strips on multiple continents that conformed to no limits whatsoever.

Comment: @mins Unless I am overlooking something the figures you quote are suggested ideal values, not intrinsic requirements, limits, or otherwise binding. I see the words `should`, `if practicable`, and `ideally`, but I do not see `shall`, `must`, or any other word indicating requirement. Any requirement or limit will likely be defined—even if only by reference to this document—in other agreements or contracts.

Comment: @JonathanWalters: ICAO recommendations must be followed by member states, or differences must be described in AIP. Correct? And as a matter of fact if we look at the [US AIP GEN 1.7−83](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIP.pdf): "*Minimum and maximum transverse runway slopes are based on aircraft approach categories as
follows: For categories A and B:  1.0 - 2.0 percent. C and D:  1.0 − 1.5 percent*"

Comment: @mins The US has adopted the ICAO recommendations as regulation for certain airports serving certain scheduled air carrier traffic. The US also generally requires federally obligated airports to conform to the adopted recommendations, but by agreement, not by regulation. Many airports within the US do not conform.

Comment: modified question - What is the acceptable tolerance for a specified transverse slope on a runway???